# Accessing a string before and after another string in an arrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

If I search for the 5th item in my arrayList, I also want to get the 4th and 6th. The code for this is provided in the final if statement and is define as (i - 1) and (i + 1). Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlanetsList {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList<String> planets = new ArrayList<String>();
    String names[] = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranis", "Neptune", "Pluto"};

    for (int i = 0, n = names.length; i < n; i++) {
        planets.add(names[i]);
        String value = (String) planets.get(i);

        if(value.contains("Mars")) {
            String newNum = value.replace(value, "Red planet ");
            planets.set(i,newNum);     
        }
        if(value.contains("Uranis")) {
            String wordBefore = (String) planets.get(i-1);
            String wordAfter = (String) planets.get(i+1);
            String newNum = value.replace(value, "Uranus ");
            planets.set(i,newNum);
            System.out.println("This is the word before " + wordBefore);
            System.out.println("This is the word after " + wordAfter);
            planets.remove(i-1);  
        }
    }
    System.out.println(planets);
}
}
```

With this I get an indexoutofbounds exception, which is obviously caused by the wordAfter line in the final if statement, and because the for loop hasn't looped through the entire arrayList. The final if statement doesn't need to be in the same for loop as the other if statement, but if it is in a different loop, the replace method must be able to put the replaced word back in the correct position.

Regards

Comment: Use generic type to avoid casting: `ArrayList<String> planets = new ArrayList<>();`, Also, why are you using `contains()` on a string when checking for equality? That's what `equals()` is for ;) Also, I don't hink your question is self-explanatory. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: This is just an example of a part of my program, not the actual thing. need the contains method for another purpose. Will adjust to generic type and review my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete adding the strings into your list and then try iterating over list again for your logic. You're trying `get(i+1)` when `i` is the max added to your list.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bring this up again. I have made an adjustment to the quetsion by adding a remove method to the final if statement. This worked up until I got my question to work. Any ideas as to why this has stopped working, since it was working before?

Comment: remove should also be working if you're using a second loop for iterating over your list after adding the items in first loop.

Answer (score 2):

This Line causes the issue.

```
 String wordAfter = (String) planets.get(i+1);
```

Because the maximum index is i.

it will be better if you do the checking as follows.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList planets = new ArrayList();
    String names[] = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranis", "Neptune", "Pluto"};

    for (int i = 0, n = names.length; i < n; i++) {
        planets.add(names[i]);

    }
    for (int i = 0, n = names.length; i < n; i++) {

        String value = (String) planets.get(i);

        if(value.contains("Mars")) {
            String newNum = value.replace(value, "Red planet ");
            planets.set(i,newNum);     
        }
        if(value.contains("Uranis")) {
            String wordBefore = (String) planets.get(i-1);
            String wordAfter = (String) planets.get(i+1);
            String newNum = value.replace(value, "Uranus ");
            planets.set(i,newNum);
            System.out.println("This is the word before " + wordBefore);
            System.out.println("This is the word after " + wordAfter);   
        }
    }
    System.out.println(planets);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

planets.add(names[i]);...In this line only you are adding a value to arraylist.At this point, the size of your arraylist is i.Without incrementing i or adding any value to arraylist, you are trying to access element at i+1..So it will definitely throw IOB exception

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem

your code was giving exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at PlanetsList.main(PlanetsList.java:20)
```

**Here is working one:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlanetsList {
public static void main(String args[]) {

ArrayList planets = new ArrayList();
String names[] = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranis", "Neptune", "Pluto"};

for (int i = 0, n = names.length; i < n; i++) {
planets.add(names[i]);
}
for (int i = 0, n = names.length; i < n; i++) {
String value = (String) planets.get(i);

if(value.contains("Mars")) {
String newNum = value.replace(value, "Red planet");
planets.set(i,newNum);     
}
 if(value.contains("Uranis")) {
String wordBefore = (String) planets.get(i-1);
String wordAfter = (String) planets.get(i+1);
String newNum = value.replace(value, "Uranus");
planets.set(i,newNum);
System.out.println("This is the word before " + wordBefore);
System.out.println("This is the word after " + wordAfter);   
 }
}
System.out.println(planets);
}
}
```

I have made two changes in your code:

1. Taken two for loops
2. remove `spaces` from following two lines

   ```
   String newNum = value.replace(value, "Red planet ");
   String newNum = value.replace(value, "Uranus ");
   ```

Comment: Thanks, got it to work with just `planets.addAll(Arrays.asList(names));`

Comment: Hi, sorry to bring this up again. If I wanted to remove items, by adding `planets.remove(i-1);` and `planets.remove(i+1);` to the final if statement, how would I get that to work. Also getting indexoutofbounds, this only shows up since I changed the code from the one in the question.

Comment: @Digitalwolf just add `break;` before closing your last `if` statement, I have tasted on my machine, it is working

Comment: Just had to make another adjustment, but yes the break did solve the error =D thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Arrays.asList to convert your array into a List and then iterate through the list to do your processing. You should check anyway that the index of wordBefore and wordAfter are within the List limits.

Answer (score 1):

I also feels that the question is not self-explanatory...But if your need is to get the element just before and after a particular item in the arraylist, you can do like this.

My assumption is that you have already a list with values pre-populated.

```
String names[] = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranis", "Neptune", "Pluto"};

List<String> planets = java.util.ArrayList.asList(names);

if (planets.contains("Uranis") ) {
   int currentIndex = planets.indexOf("Uranis");       
   String previousItem = planets.get(currentIndex-1);
   // To ensure that we have an element next to the current one. 
   if (currentIndex < (planets.size() - 1 )) {
    String nextItem = planets.get(currentIndex+1); 
   }
}
```

I hope this will help you

~Ragesh